# SSL settings for SOAPConnection in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, soap

I am sending a soap request and receiving a soap response using SOAPConnection as follows:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
            .newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
  response = connection.call(message, urlEndPoint);
```

I need to set host name verifier. If I were using HttpsURLConnection, I could acchieve it this way:

```
 HttpsURLConnection     connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setHostnameVerifier((String hostName, SSLSession ssls) -> hostName.equals("serverHostName"));
```

How can I achieve this using SOAPConnection?

Comment: By default, if urlEndPoint is HTTPS, then it automatically handles HttpsURLConnection, so why you need to additionally verify the host?

Comment: @RedBoy The problem is that I am getting this exception **hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate** which is an issue with the certificate. Since I don't have control at the server side, I want to put a workaround here.

Comment: OK, you could pass connection object instead of urlEndPoint in your code example. ***response = connection.call(message, connection);***